# error connecting to mongodb on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb from node and I am getting below error

> node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:458
>             throw err
>             ^
>
> ReferenceError: connect is not defined

I am using the mongodb module version 
2.0.48

I am trying to run a simple test code

```
 (function (dbase) {

    var mdb = require('mongodb');
    var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/theBoard";
    var connection;

    dbase.dbConnection = function (next) {
        if (connection) {
            next(null, connection);
        } else {
            mdb.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err, null);
                } else {
                    console.log("connected");                        
                    connection = { db: db , notes: db.collection("notes")};
                    next(null, connection);

                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Can someone please help me understand this issue.

---Additional information

data module -

```
(function (data) {
var mdb = require('./db.js');

data.GetCategory = function() {
    mdb.dbConnection(function(err, db) {

        if (err)
            console.log("Error connecting to mango");
        if (connect) {
            db.notes.count(function(err, count) {
                if (err)
                    console.log("Failed to retreive collection");
                else
                    console.log("Count - "+count);

            });

            console.log("Connected");
        }

    });
}})(module.exports);
```

db.js

```
(function (dbase) {

var mdb = require('mongodb');
var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/theBoard";
var connection;

dbase.dbConnection = function (next) {
    if (connection) {
        next(null, connection);
    } else {
        mdb.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
                next(err, null);
            } else {
                console.log("connected");
                connection = { db: db , notes: db.collection("notes") };


               next(null, connection);

            }
        });
    }

}    })(module.exports);
```

Controller -

```
(function (controller) {
    var data = require('.././data');

    controller.init = function (app) {
        app.get("/", handleRequest);
    }

    var handleRequest = function (req, res) {
        data.GetCategory();

        var a = {};
        a.send = "Mamma is coming home";
        res.send(a);
    }

})(module.exports);
```

Comment: tried this  `mdb.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {...` line in sample code it gives no error . try putting this line outside function dbase.dbConnection and then what error u get ?

Comment: I have added a complete walk through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case some one runs into an issue like this due to bad coding practice even if it for test purpose is to never have function names which are the same as the function names in the API. In db.js I had an undefined variable named connect which trowing and error when it was accessed and since it was called through the API function called "connect" the error was thrown by the API leading me to believe that the API function had an issue